# Object with same key already exists in objectstatemanager.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm getting below error while updating two tables using entity framework -

> Object with same key already exists in objectstatemanager. The existing object is in the modified state. An object can only added to objectstatemanager again if it is in added state

My code

```
public void UpdatePaymentTransaction(PaymentTransaction paymentTransaction)
    {
        using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
        {
            var entity = context.PaymentTransactionEntities.Where(c => c.Id == paymentTransaction.Id).SingleOrDefault();

                entity.PartyId = paymentTransaction.PartyId;                
                entity.TotalAmount = paymentTransaction.TotalAmount;                
                entity.RequestDate = paymentTransaction.RequestDate;                
                entity.ResponseDate = paymentTransaction.ResponseDate;

            context.PaymentTransactionEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();

            if (paymentTransaction.PaymentGatewayOrderId != null)
            {
                PaymentTransactionContractEntity paymentTransactionContractEntity = new PaymentTransactionContractEntity();
                string[] contractIds = paymentTransaction.PaymentGatewayOrderId.Split('-');

                foreach (var contractId in contractIds)
                {
                    paymentTransactionContractEntity.PaymentTransactionId = entity.Id;
                    paymentTransactionContractEntity.ContractId = Convert.ToInt32(contractId);
                    context.PaymentTransactionContractEntities.AddObject(paymentTransactionContractEntity);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public void UpdatePaymentTransaction(PaymentTransaction paymentTransaction)
{
    using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
    {
        var entity = context.PaymentTransactionEntities.Where(c => c.Id == paymentTransaction.Id).SingleOrDefault();

        entity.PartyId = paymentTransaction.PartyId;                
        entity.TotalAmount = paymentTransaction.TotalAmount;                
        entity.RequestDate = paymentTransaction.RequestDate;                
        entity.ResponseDate = paymentTransaction.ResponseDate;

        // Either use previous for rows or following row. Both are not needed
        //context.PaymentTransactionEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();

        if (paymentTransaction.PaymentGatewayOrderId != null)
        {
            string[] contractIds = paymentTransaction.PaymentGatewayOrderId.Split('-');

            foreach (var contractId in contractIds)
            {
                // Create new instance for each loop otherwise only first contract
                // is considered as insert and all following contracts only modifies
                // the first one = reason for your exception
                PaymentTransactionContractEntity paymentTransactionContractEntity = new PaymentTransactionContractEntity();

                paymentTransactionContractEntity.PaymentTransactionId = entity.Id;
                paymentTransactionContractEntity.ContractId = Convert.ToInt32(contractId);
                context.PaymentTransactionContractEntities.AddObject(paymentTransactionContractEntity);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```