# The entity type List`1 is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I've been using Database First, EF 4.1

I am getting "The entity type List`1 is not part of the model for the current context." error when trying to update a record from my Edit View.

The error is occurring at

```
db.Entry(properties).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Here is my Model:

```
public class Users
     {
     [Key]
     public int User_ID { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     public IEnumerable<App_Properties> User_Properties
     {
          get { return Properties.Where(u => u.User_ID == User_ID); }
     }

     public virtual ICollection<App_Properties> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class App_Properties
{
     [Key]
     public int Prop_ID { get; set; }
     public int User_ID { get; set; }
     public int App_ID { get; set; }
     public string Key { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }
     public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
     public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("User_ID")]
     public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ICollection<App_Properties> properties)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          foreach (var item in properties)
          {
               db.Entry(properties).State = EntityState.Modified;
          }

          db.SaveChanges();

          return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }

     return View(properties);
}
```

I suspect the foreach loop is not appropriate in setting the EntityState for each item in an ICollection.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A quick semantic note, the name App_Properties.Users would imply multiple users, not one.  Convention tends to be that a single object has a singular name as saying `var users = new Users()` implies a collection of people, not a single item.

Comment: Yeah, thanks... I have no control of the DB and I let the improper naming of the tables propagate down into my code.

Comment: The db names don't have to though - it's very easy to change the mapping of your POCO to the actual database table OnModelCreating: `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users")`.  A simple F2 rename on the Users class will then propagate the rename across your project.  Same with property names - you can custom map any of it.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try changing your loop to:

```
foreach (var item in properties)
{
     db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

You were calling `db.Entry(properties)`, so you were trying to attach the whole collection at once.  DbContext.Entry(object) [expects a single object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696238%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), not a collection.

Comment: Thanks.. That got rid of that error but added a "Object with same key already exists in objectstatemanager error." I was able to get help with that error from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254854/object-with-same-key-already-exists-in-objectstatemanager.

Comment: Thanks ... this was helpful

Comment: I got an idea from your answer so I did the following:
I am using code first approach with LazyLoadingEnabled = false
I had a collection of actions against a status so I loaded then like that
dbContext.Entry(status).Collection(c=>c.Actions).Load\();

Comment: It worked fine but issue arises when I found that there is an object which is related to each Action NextStatus so I used the following:
foreach(var a in status.Actions)
{
     dbContext.Entry(a).Reference(c=>c.nextStatsu).Load();
}

Answer (score 13):

Thanks, Leniency, for the answer. Worked great.

For what it's worth, I prefer to keep my `EntityState.Modified` assignments on a single line (as I have multiples) so used the following LINQ:

```
properties.ForEach(p => db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here despite using code-first EF. The answer to the problem for me was simply not to try to pass a list of entities to the insert method, but insert them one at a time instead:

`entityList.ForEach(context.Insert);`

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this code for this problem. Because if you use it, you will met another problem. Now i fixed my problem and i hope it will work for you

```
foreach (var item in properties)
{
  var oldEntity = FGetById(item.Id); // You can use find instead of FGetById
  context.Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
  Update(oldEntity);
}
```