# updating multiple rows in a table at once using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to update few records in a table at once.

So I have table like below

[image]

Its loading 30 editor for both `Field_Value_EN` and `Field_Value_AR` per one `Product_ID`

like below

[image]

these are relevant model classes

AB_Product_vs_Field model class

```
public partial class AB_Product_vs_Field
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_Value_EN { get; set; }
    public string Field_Value_AR { get; set; }
}
```

ProductEdit model class

```
public class ProductEdit
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Subsidary_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameAr { get; set; }
    public string ApprovalStatus { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public IList<AB_Product_vs_Field> ListProductFields { get; set; }
    public IList<AB_ProductTypeCategoryField> ListProductLables { get; set; }
}
```

Once I submit details I want to update all the relevant rows `AB_Product_vs_Field` table.

Eg: lets say I update **Product_ID = 10** records , its should be update all the rows relavant to **Product_ID = 10**

So I created my linq query like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Product_Edit(ProductEdit product)
    {
        AB_Product_vs_Field insertproductvalue = new AB_Product_vs_Field();      
        var user = db.AspNetUsers.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var listInsertproductvalue = new List<AB_Product_vs_Field>(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < product.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
            {
                listInsertproductvalue.Add(new AB_Product_vs_Field
                {
                    Product_ID = product.Product_ID,
                    Field_ID = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_ID,
                    Field_Value_EN = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN,
                    Field_Value_AR = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_AR
                }); 

            };

            db.Entry(listInsertproductvalue).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

but here I'm getting following error in `db.Entry(listInsertproductvalue).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;`   line

> The entity type List`1 is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

---

**EDIT**

then I changed LINQ query like this

```
        AB_Product_vs_Field insertproductvalue = new AB_Product_vs_Field();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < product.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
            {
                insertproductvalue.Field_ID = product.Product_ID;
                insertproductvalue.Product_ID = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_ID;
                insertproductvalue.Field_Value_EN = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN;
                insertproductvalue.Field_Value_AR = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_AR;


            };
            db.Entry(insertproductvalue).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

but then getting following error

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded.

Comment: i think db.Entry expects single object not list

Comment: so then how to convert this for list

Comment: Do you have to specify the .State's value?

Comment: cannot understand what you said

Comment: I thought you are finding [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896569/the-entity-type-list1-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context) answer

Comment: @MapleStory nope I visited that question before post this question, tried it, that not worked for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Just try updating the entity *inside* the loop:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Product_Edit(ProductEdit product)
    {
        var user = db.AspNetUsers.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < product.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
            {
                var insertproductvalue = new AB_Product_vs_Field
                {
                    Product_ID = product.Product_ID,
                    Field_ID = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_ID,
                    Field_Value_EN = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN,
                    Field_Value_AR = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_AR
                }); 

                // Attach and set to modified
                db.Entry(insertproductvalue).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            };

            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: then I'm getting following error `The key field 'Product_ID' cannot have a value of null. A non-null value is required for the key fields defined on type 'AB_Product_vs_Field'.`

Comment: This means that the value of `product.Product_ID` is `null`. When you pass the product model to the edit method you must provide the ID of the product you want to edit.

Comment: yes I'm passing , currently its hard coded in GET method             as Product_ID = "01";

Comment: Then, somewhere between your GET and the PUT, you forgot to copy the `Product_ID`. By the way: I don't think it's a good idea to use `string`s as IDs. Better use `int`s or `Guid`s for that.

Comment: @kez, so what is you current problem now? Is it the unexpected null reference or the concurrency error ("Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.")? Either way, those are different errors. The solution for you original question was provided, so please mark it as an answer.

Comment: @kez, as to your concurrency errors: try googling the error message and you will find lots of suggestions how to handle this. Basically you have to add something called a "row version" to your model. Transmit the product model along with row version to the client, edit the model and send it back to the server with the same row version. Entity Framework then checks if a client that tries to update something in the DB had the most current version of the model before changing it.