# How to Update/Edit multiple records using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to update multiple records, this is how far I could get

First, I tried this

```
foreach (var Product in Products)
{
     Product.Price = Price;

     db.Entry(Product).State = EntityState.Modified;
     db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

But, I'm getting this error

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Then, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254854/object-with-same-key-already-exists-in-objectstatemanager) answer, saying that I should create new instance for each iteration, but I got the same error. Below is my attempt.

```
foreach (var Product in Products)
{
     var ProductInLoop = new Product();
     ProductInLoop.Price = Product.Price;

     db.Entry(ProductInLoop).State = EntityState.Modified;
     db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Also I can't do it like this `db.Entry(Products).State = EntityState.Modified;` outside the loop, because `Entry()` expects a singel object.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you looping through `Products` yet repeatedly setting the values of  `ProductSize` or `ProductInLoop` and ignoring the loop variable `Product`?

Comment: Why are u creating new `Products`in your loop? You want to update the existing ones, right?

Comment: Thanks @BenRobinson , the problem was like you said, it was the Primary Key = 0, I solved it thanks to you. Regarding `ProductSize`, I'm actually updating `ProductSize`, instead of `Product`, but I removed all unrelated code trying to simplify/focus on the problem, but I forgot to change it.

Comment: please call savechanges outside the loop call it only one time

Comment: @BenRobinson can you sir see my post same error how to solve it and I dont know I passwed the primary key in correct way or not ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72825364/store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpected-number-of-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Ben Robinson's comment, I solved this. The problem caused because I didn't pass the *primary key* from *View* to *Controller*.

In *View* I added this hidden field to pass the *primary key*s like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="[@i].id" value="@Product.id" />
```

and server side code look like this

```
foreach (var product in Products)
{
    product.Price = Price;

    db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
 }
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hello sir can you please see the error same this error but I don't know where is the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72825364/store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpected-number-of-rows

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a new Product object. Since you are modifying records, your Products collection is likely already attached to the database context, and it's state will be tracked if you modify it.

Try this:

```
foreach (var Product in Products)
{        
     Product.price = ProductSize.price;
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

if the Products are not attached to the context (db), add this line before saving:

```
db.Products.Attach(Product);
```

by convention, you should also change your looping variable from Prodcut to the lowercase form : product

Comment: I solved it thanks to Ben Robinson comment. I didn't pass the primary key from view to controller, and it was equal to zero, and that caused the error. Once I passed it, the problem resolved. Also thanks for the convention advice.