# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got the following entity framework error while trying to save edit page

```
   "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded."
```

This is my EDIT controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(RESULT results)
        {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Entry(results).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }
            return View(results);
        }
```

I need to update multiple rows (Result column value only)

and I checked the solutions in the site

and I added the primary key ID column see the image :

[image]

this is the EDIT view code :

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().custid)
        </td>
       
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().TESTID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().LabTest.TestName)
        </td>
        
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().RESULT1)
        </td>
       
    </tr>
      @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
      {
          <tr>
               
              <td>
                  @Html.TextBox("RESULTS[" + @i + "].ID", Model[i].ID, new { @readonly = "readonly" })

              </td>
              <td>
                  @Html.TextBox("RESULTS[" + @i + "].custid", Model[i].custid, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                  
              </td>
               <td>
                  @Html.TextBox("RESULTS[" + @i + "].TESTID", Model[i].TESTID, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
              </td>
              <td>
                  @Html.TextBox("LabTest[" + @i + "].TestName", Model[i].LabTest.TestName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
              </td>
             
              <td>
                  @Html.TextBox("RESULTS[" + @i + "].RESULT1", Model[i].RESULT1)
              </td>
            
          </tr>
      }
</table>  
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" style="margin:100px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

What is the missing in my code please I need your help ?

Comment: On submit are you able to get model data on the edit method?

Comment: @RamAnugandula what do you mean ? when I click SAVE it show this error

Comment: It's not hitting your controller action method?

Comment: @RamAnugandula I don't know actually this is first time I use this method  EntityState.Modified and I think there is a missing

Comment: @RamAnugandula I found this solution that must pass the primary key to the controller but I don't know I did it correct way or not     "In View I added this hidden field to pass the primary keys like this:

<input type="hidden" name="[@i].id" value="@Product.id" />"   ?

Comment: You need to iterate all results item

Comment: @Dans I will try the solution , also I found another solution thank you so much , but I have error I need to use ViewBab.Message but when click save its save the updates but not show the message and show error "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" what is the error with viewBag ?

Comment: 1) always check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Controller Action, the parameter should be the List. You need to iterate and update.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(List<RESULT> results)
    {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach(var item in results)
            {
                var model =_context.Find(item.ID);
                if(model != null) {  
                   model.TestID = item.TestID;
                   model.TestName = item.TestName;
                   //update columns you want to update
                   _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Updated Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }
        return View(results);
    }
```

View

```
@if(ViewBag.Message != null){
   @ViewBag.Message
}
```

Comment: what if ID not found it gives **object reference not set to an instance of an object** exception

Comment: can you add ViewBag message after save I tried it but got error perform runtime binding on a null reference    what is the error ?   I added it to controller and view  ViewBag.Message("Updated Successfully");

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I changed the code as the following :

Edit controller code :

```
 public ActionResult Edit(List<RESULT> list)
        {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (db_Entities db = new db_Entities())
                {
                    foreach (var i in list)
                    {
                        var c = db.RESULTS.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(i.ID)).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (c != null)
                        {
                            c.RESULT1 = i.RESULT1;
                        }
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    
                }
             //   ViewBag.Message("Updated Successfully");
                return View(list);
            }
            else
            {
              //  ViewBag.Message("Failed ! Please try again");
                return View(list);
            }        

        }
```

EDIT view code :

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        
        <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().custid) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().TESTID) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().LabTest.TestName) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_BY) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().RESULT1) </td>
       
    </tr>
      @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
      {
          <tr>
           
              <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ID)</td>
              <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].custid)</td>
              <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].TESTID)</td>
              <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].LabTest.TestName)</td>
              <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].APPROVED_BY)</td>
              <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].APPROVED_DATE)</td>
              <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].RESULT1)</td>
              
            
          </tr>
      }
</table>
 
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" style="margin:100px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-danger" />
           </div>
    </div>
    @*<p style="color:green;font-size:16px;">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </p>*@
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified  based on @Ram Anugandula Logic we can save data after completion of loop because objects are reference type and we can save the after modify entire object

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(List<RESULT> Input)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach(var item in Input)
        {
            var model =_context.Yourdbsetentity.Find(item.ID);
            If(model!=null){
            model.TestID = item.TestID;
            model.TestName = item.TestName;
            //update columns you want to update
             }else{
               model=new RESULT();
               model.TestID = item.TestID;
               model.TestName = item.TestName;
              //Create columns you want to update
             _context.Yourdbsetentity.add(model)
           }
        }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    }
    return View(results);
}
```